# Can't add to List

Tags: java, swing, listbox

I have a List box in my UI design, however, I can't access the `.getElement()` method that many people seem to be accessing when implementing a get method.

Is there any reason for this and is there a way to add values to this list box?

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: Show some code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a List box in my UI design,

I assume you mean `JList` when using Swing. "List" is an AWT component. Be specific when you ask a question to avoid confusion.

> Is there any reason for this and is there a way to add values to this list box?

You add items to the `DefaultListModel`, not the `JList`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and working examples.